# Network printers randomly print blank documents

Tags: local-area-network, printing, printer, network-printer

We have two printers connected straight through Ethernet without a print server, one is a [Samsung M2875FD](http://www.samsung.com/uk/consumer/print-solutions/print-solutions/mono-multi-function-products/SL-M2875FD/SEE), and the other one a [Dell 1320c](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/product/dell-1320cn/drivers). Since we installed the Samsung printer, everybody noticed that **they started randomly printing blank documents**.

This is what we did so far:

- Install the drivers Windows suggest (they come with the nice Print properties of the printer itself, so they should be the original ones)
- Remove every driver related to this printer, and install the ones coming with the printer. We even installed the "extra software" coming with them.
- Remove all the drivers related to the printer, and install the ones from the Samsung support page.
- Print a document with an extra step called print preview (it comes with the Samsung printer). Surprise, it sometimes shows a blank document. *Here's where we made the assumption of the issue coming from the computer*
- Use different applications to print the same documents. Again, it randomly returns a nice set of blank pages.

Any issue related to LAN connection/toner/drum/paper jams has been addressed. How should one proceed, in this case?

Edit: After doing some tests, it looks like Mac is not having the issue, but I couldn't be sure.

Edit2: This "it prints nice or it prints blank pages" happens randomly, **even trying to print the same document twice**. So you try to print May_Report.odt and it just throws 3 blank pages, and trying to print it again, it just runs well.

Edit3: Definitely, the Mac computer doesn't have issues, but curiously enough, one of our computers doesn't have the Samsung drivers installed, and it prints well with the Dell.

Comment: How many computers do you have?

Comment: @KonradGajewski About 20 Windows 7-8 and a Mac mini (2013)

Comment: How often, and when does this blank thing happen? (You mentioned leaving the computer - do you mean shutdown?)

Comment: @KonradGajewski I reformulated that sentence a little =), it happens randomly, maybe only 60% of the documents are printed.

Comment: Do the documents have comments / tracked changes enabled? If so try stripping those out and try printing the document again.

Comment: @DKNUCKLES I forgot something important... this issue may happen randomly on the same document! It doesn't look like it's related to contebts in documents at all, sadly

Comment: @Korcholis are you using a print server? Or are all workstations connected to the network printer directly?

Comment: The more we get into it, the less I understand. So now it is not only blank pages, but some of documents not being printed?

Comment: @KonradGajewski yeah well, I wrote really fast from the phone and didn't make it clear enough. The same document is printed well or with blank pages.

Comment: @DKNUCKLES No print server inbetween, precisely we picked these printers because they can be connected without an intermediary computer.

Comment: Hello, random downvoter! Would you mind explaining your decision?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, so basically we've seen a lot of stuff so far, and I can be pretty sure to say that this issue **is related to the Windows Samsung Driver**.

Somehow, after installing it, it possibly corrupts a shared library with the Dell drivers, causing both printers to fail at printing sometimes.

### Why am I sure?

All the Windows computers with Dell's and Samsung's drivers print documents ok, but after some time, they randomly print blank documents (the proper amount of pages per document, but blank).

The only computer with the Dell's drivers prints properly (only on the Dell, of course).

The Mac computer, which prints over AirPlay, works perfectly with the Samsung One.

### What could we do now?

Since the only one working well is the Mac one, I could convert it into a print server, but it's not a perfect solution, since this computer is not sure to be on during office hours.

The only thing I can think of, is contacting the Samsung Technical Support and ask them for a new version of their Windows Drivers. However, the first time we contacted the Samsung's TS, they told us to return the printer back and buy another one. It looks like they don't have a proper way to solve it.

Comment: Hello, random downvoter! Would you mind explaining your decision?